# Android: get camera data to Bitmap for continues scaning

Tags: android, bitmap, android-camera, zxing, android-framelayout

I'm developing android application for bar-code reading without using app support but using **zxing library**. I have set the `CameraView` to a `FrameLayout`

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="223dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.35"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </FrameLayout>
```

in the code I can view the camera view in frame layout.

```
    private Camera cameraObject;
    cameraObject = isCameraAvailable();
    showCamera=new ShowCamera(this, cameraObject);
    FrameLayout preview=(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(showCamera);
```

showCamera class is,

```
public class ShowCamera extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private SurfaceHolder holdMe;
private Camera theCamera;


public  ShowCamera(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    theCamera=camera;
    holdMe=getHolder();
    holdMe.addCallback(this);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try{
        theCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        theCamera.startPreview();


    }catch(IOException er){
        /// nothing yet to have any function to perform
    }
}
```

now I want to get that data and send it to `MultiFormatReader()` save the image into device and get that image to scan is not effective. I want to get the preview data from the camera after focus complete and convert current preview data into `Bitmap` object. can someone help me?

Comment: You want to integrate scanning into your fragment or activity?

Comment: I want scanning into activity.

Comment: I am asking because i did this in one project and it was extremely painful. I suggest you to use android libraries(from github) based on barcode scanner application from zxing. On other hand if you want very custom implementation and custom integration in your app - you should investigate soure code of barcode scanner application provided by zxing.

Comment: yes I'm using google android zxing library. but I don't use client application that has to install with google apps developed by zxing team.

Comment: you can look at source code of samples provided by zxing to find how to provide data from camera directly to decoder.